# Fetch data from 3 Tables

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have 3 Tables

1 Customers 
-c_id 
-c_name

2 Debit_Master 
-transaction_id
-c_id
-amount

3 Credit_Master
-transaction_id
-c_id
-amount

Now i want data like this : Customer Name and Total amount(credit amount - debit amount) of each customer .

I want query to fetch data in my listview with two columns 1- Customer Name , 2- Total amount

Comment: So, what's the issue? What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    Customers.c_name as CustomerName, 
    SUM((CASE
           WHEN Credit_Master.amount IS NULL THEN 0 
           ELSE Credit_Master.amount END - 
         CASE 
           WHEN Debit_Master.amount IS NULL THEN 0 
           ELSE Debit_Master.amount END)) as TotalAmount
FROM Customers 
  LEFT JOIN Debit_Master on Customers.c_id = Debit_Master.c_id 
  LEFT JOIN Credit_Master on Customers.c_id = Credit_Master.c_id
GROUP BY Customers.c_id
```

Comment: This is what i want ! You totally read my mind. Natali's ans is correct but list view does not display anything until there are transactions on both debit-credit table. I think it will help me . I will check it and get back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
   SELECT Customers.c_name as name , (Credit_Master.amount - Debit_Master.amount) as total FROM Customers JOIN Debit_Master on Customers.c_id=Debit_Master.c_id JOIN Credit_Master on Customers.c_id=Credit_Master.c_id
```